# very simple mod_rewrite replacing "forums" to "forum"

Tags: mod-rewrite, url

Can somebody help me with a mod_rewrite rule for this situation?
I only need to remove the ‘s’ from a forums segment.

From

```
 www.test.com/test-forums/anystring/anystring
```

or

```
test.com/test-forums/anystring/anystring
```

To

```
/test-forum/anystring/anystring
```

So to speak, only S at the end of "forums" is removed.

Any help would be great.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your VirtualHost:80 section:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ... other configuration ...

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/test-forums(.*) /test-forum$1
</VirtualHost>
```

This will leave the url in the browser address bar as www.test.com/test-forums/anystring/anystring

If you want to send a redirect to the browser so the url displayed in the address bar becomes www.test.com/test-forum/anystring/anystring, add `[L,R=301]` to the RewriteRule line:

```
RewriteRule ^/test-forums(.*) /test-forum$1 [L,R=301]
```